# Windows Terminal haves 256 color support?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, colors

A teacher has sent us an exercise in which we have to use the terminal to display an image as ASCII, if we can put color on it, it is a 10.

Originally, the exercise is proposed for Linux, but I wonder if this can be done in the new Windows Terminal.

I know for Linux or Osx there are tools like `gif-for-cli` and I would like to know if there is support for 256 colors in Windows.
Thank you.
P.D:

The script has to be in python

**EDIT**

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/2762225) that prompts all 256 colors in the terminal. So I think the answer is yes

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to just import [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/), and it will automatically convert anything that was meant to print colored output in Linux print colored output in Windows. See [How to print colored text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used colorama. But I'm find [this](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/2762225) that shows what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, because you can choose every color in the cmd settings[image]